# findViewById returns null when call this in a class that extend on RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, android-relativelayout, findviewbyid

I'm trying to get a layout with the findViewById method that I have in my activity_main from a class that I created.
This class extends RelativeLayout and within the constructor I am trying to implement the onClick method for the user when they click on the RelativeLayout, this create another layout, so I need to get that layout to add to the view.

This is the code where I get the NPE:

```
public class PatientBoxLayout extends RelativeLayout {

/**
 * 
 */
private Patient patient;

/**
 * Constructor de la clase Patient Box
 * 
 * @param context
 * @param patient
 */

public static double coefi = 3.3;

public PatientBoxLayout(Context aContext, Patient aPatient) {
    super(aContext);

    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            RelativeLayout horizontalLL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.upp_layout);
            horizontalLL.addView(new PatientBoxLayout(v.getContext(),
                    ((PatientBoxLayout) v).getPatient()));
        }
    });
```

This is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/upp_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="258dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:text="Paciente" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewNomPaciente"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="Edad" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewEdadPaciente"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textViewNomPaciente"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Cama" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewCamaPaciente"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewEdadPaciente"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
                    android:text="Sexo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewCamaPaciente"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewNomPaciente"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewNomPaciente"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="NHC" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewEdadPaciente"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewEdadPaciente"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
                    android:text="Episodio" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewCamaPaciente"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewCamaPaciente"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
                    android:text="Diagnostico" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewNHCPaciente"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewEpisodioPaciente"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewNHCPaciente"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewDiagnosticoPaciente"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewEpisodioPaciente"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewNHCPaciente"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewNHCPaciente"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="79dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewNHCPaciente"
                    android:text="FIngreso" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewEpisodioPaciente"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewEpisodioPaciente"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
                    android:text="Servicio" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewDiagnosticoPaciente"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
                    android:text="Alergias" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
                    android:text="Aislado" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewFIngresoPaciente"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView9"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewServicioPaciente"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewFIngresoPaciente"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewA"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewServicioPaciente"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewAisladoPaciente"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewA"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/down_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dip"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>
                <!-- Contenido principal -->

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Contenido principal -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#EEE"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_single_choice" >
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope you can help me identify the layout from the constructor of the class.

Thank you.
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you check on the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html both activity and view have a `findViewById` method.

So when you're calling `findViewById(R.id.upp_layout);` inside the `PatientBoxLayout` is trying to find that view only inside its own layout tree. And it can't find because it's not there. So it returns null and you crash with `NullPointerException` on the next line.

You can call `getParent()` to navigate up in the layout hierarchy and then call there the `findViewById(R.id.upp_layout);` or an even better solution is to not to put ClickListener inside a view or viewGroup. Those are not meant to handle clicks. You should handle the clicks on the Activity or Fragment.

Comment: "even better solution is to not to put ClickListener inside a view or viewGroup. Those are not meant to handle clicks. You should handle the clicks on the Activity or Fragment." That worked for me.

Comment: +1 for the "not handling clicks in a View" part. Even though Android is built on solid MVC principles, it seems surprisingly easy to break those principles and make a spaghetti app.